# JavaScript - if #id equals something

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't the following code work?

```
        var err = document.getElementById("text-error").value;
        if (err == "Team already exists") {
            $('#text-error').fadeIn(400).delay(3200).fadeOut(800);
        }
```

The error does not fade in or fade out.

Checked the console - no problems.

Also, this particular error is sent via the server.

The fade in and fade out work for my client side errors - but not errors pertaining to my database like this one - if that makes any difference to the problem.

---

UPDATE

After console logging - I realize that it does not enter the if statement, even though it clearly equals it - via html code and via a quick glance at the page.

Comment: What is it doing and what should it do instead? Some context would be nice.

Comment: I'm like brand new to JS - so I assumed it would be some silly error that I was not aware of - I have now added more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have something like

```
<div id="text-error> Team already exists </div>
```

If so, then replace your first line of code with

```
var err = document.getElementById("text-error").innerText;
```

JsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fCNe8/

Comment: This worked. Congratulations Sir Nguyen - please have a chocolate chip cookie courtesy of JoseBazBaz

Comment: for browser compatibility, you should use innerHTML instead of innerText, cause some browsers do not support innerText. if you compare a string(get from html element)  is equals to a specified string,you'd better trim it.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
 var err = $("#text-error").val();
    if (err == "Team already exists") {
        console.log('is equal but problem is fadeing not working');
        $('#text-error').fadeIn(400).delay(3200).fadeOut(800);
    }else {
        console.log('not equal');
    }
```

but ofcourse more details about the issue will help us

Comment: LOL This doesn't solve the problem - in fact you should probably just not use an err variable for this just use text-error.val()

Comment: so there where your problem is!

Comment: @Blender Yes, that's helps, cause framework meant to be crossbrowser for dealing with DOM elements, not sure what browser is testing on, but maybe it does not support .value attribute!

Comment: While this did not solve the problem - without it - it would not have been solved - I cannot give you the correct answer - since it did not solve it - but I can give you a choco chip cookie and a +1,enjoy!

Comment: It could be a problem with newlines or the like.